# Seeking pgrouting workshop or tutorial?

Tags: pgrouting, references

Please recommend pgrouting tutorials or workshops that are most current.

I ask because I just read a post that claims a tutorial is deprecated. (see osm2po vs osm2pgrouting: workshop post)

I am working through the pgrouting-workshop (http://workshop.pgrouting.org/) and find it mostly helpful.

The OS and environment here:  ubuntu 12.04, postgres 9.1, postgis 1.5.

While it may be unreasonable to ask that all deprecated tutorials be so marked, it would help if the date of authorship is included prominently in the header of all training materials, then newbies would know to expect some staleness.

Answer (score 9):

To answer the question directly, I think that [the official workshop](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/) is always the latest

Comment: Attention: the link is right, but then you should click on the name of the workshop to open the content of the workshop and access to the tutorial, i.e. the [Bonn 2016 workshop tutorial](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/2.1.0-dev/en/index.html)